# bigsqcup too small with xypic

Tags: xy-pic

I have the following issue with xypic: `\bigsqcup` looks too small (I tried to put `@R=10em` to make it bigger but that does not work :-)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath,a4wide,graphicx,stmaryrd,fullpage,setspace,microtype,ulem,textcomp,tikz,enumitem,accents}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{backref}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\setstretch{1.1}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigsqcup_{\substack{(\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n)\\\sum_i \ell_i = 1}} X^{\ell_i}
\]

\[
\xymatrix@R=10em
{
    \bigsqcup\limits_{\substack{(\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n)\\\sum_i \ell_i = 1}} X^{\ell_i}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make `\bigsqcup` bigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells in an `xymatrix` are typeset in `\textstyle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigsqcup_{\substack{(\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n)\\\sum_i \ell_i = 1}} X^{\ell_i} \to Y
\]

\[
\xymatrix@R=10em{
    \displaystyle\bigsqcup_{\substack{(\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n)\\\sum_i \ell_i = 1}} X^{\ell_i}
    \ar[r] & Y
}
\]
\end{document}
```

I removed the irrelevant packages and added `cmtip` to make for decent arrow tips.

[image]